# opening another file with path relative to current directory

Tags: working-directory

I want to open another file in the same directory or any file with its path relative to the current directory  in command line.

My path is `/home/sibich/`

```
 /home/sibich> vim a.pl
```

In vim,  I want to open b.pl in same directory, so I use :

```
:vim b.pl
```

Bit I receive this message `Invalid pattern or filename`

So, I had to give it in shell.

```
  :!vim b.pl
```

I want to directly execute this in vim.

Example 2: sub is a folder under `/home/sibich`

```
  :vim sub/c.pl
```

Is there a way to set options such that command line accepts path relative to current directory and allows opening files through split, tabnew and vim commands?

Comment: `:vim` is short for `:vimgrep`.  Is there a reason you aren't using `:e`?

Comment: This is the most basic usage of vim, have you used `vimtutor` or used google to [find](http://askubuntu.com/q/537935/408927) [a](http://www.slackbook.org/html/vi-opening-files.html) [solution](http://www.radford.edu/~mhtay/CPSC120/VIM_Editor_Commands.htm)?

Comment: @statox: I have been using vim for over a year without knowing anything about it apart from i, dd and wq!. Only for past few weeks, I am learning it through various resources. I have read vimtutor too and didnt notice this. :/ Before asking a question here, I usually Google it and then search in stackoverflow too. I am a beginner   :)

Comment: @SibiCoder: I really don't consider myself as an expert and I do understand that as beginners we sometimes have questions which might be trivial. I was just pointing out that this particular question is answered is several different places. I would never want to discourage someone from asking for help: it's the purpose of this community. It's just that on this particular topic a Google research would have provided you an answer and avoided several downvotes :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried the edit command?

```
:edit b.pl
```

Edit: Not sure if you edited in the last question, or I just missed it the first time. But the only reason you wouldn't be able to use relative paths on `:split` or `:tabnew` is if your current working directory isn't the same as the file you're currently editing. So I think what you're looking for is

```
:set autochdir
```

This option basically makes your current working directory "follow" you whenever you change buffers. With that options set, you should be able to use relative paths. See `:h autochdir` for more info.

Comment: Thanks. //current working directory isn't the same as the file editing.// I have mistaken the path of the first file to be its current directory. That is, whenever I give the vim command from shell,  I believed that the file's directory is the current directory.

Comment: Autochdir is the thing I wanted.

Answer (score 19):

Use `:e %:h<filename>`, or specifically for your question `:e %:hb.pl`. Individually these tokens mean

`:e`          edit, but you could use :tabnew or :split etc

`%`           the current file path

`:h`          'head', which in this usage is the directory of the currently open file

`<filename>`  the relative path of the file you want to open

You can also hit `tab` after typing `:h` for a list of filenames at that path.

For further reading, execute `:help expand()` in vi(m) for more about token expansion.

Comment: Thanks, this :h - tab is very helpful. but how do I browse the current directory(after :set autochdir) without making another split vim window? I mean I want to browse the directory in the current wim window (of course the current file shouldn't have any change). ==> Ah, it's just :Explore or :Ex in short. Hope this helps to anyone else.

Comment: `gf` but relative path of the file `nnoremap <Leader>gf :hide :edit %:h/<cfile><CR>`